# Filling listview with gradient background color

Tags: delphi, listview

iam trying to draw gradient Background over list view using `GraphUtil` , i have only problem with gradient position

here is my custom list view draw event

```
Var
  R: TRect;
begin
  // Full ListView
  SetRect(R, ARect.Left, ARect.Top, ARect.Right - ((ARect.Right-ARect.Left) div 2), ARect.Bottom );
  GradientFillCanvas(Sender.Canvas, panelemo.Color, clWhite, R, gdVertical); // GraphUtil
  SetRect(R, ARect.Right - ((ARect.Right-ARect.Left) div 2), ARect.Top, ARect.Right, ARect.Bottom );
  GradientFillCanvas(Sender.Canvas, panelemo.Color, clWhite, R, gdVertical);
  panelmeter.Color := panelemo.Color;
```

i want to draw gradient from right to left not from top to bottom like this image

[image]

Comment: `gdVertical` → `gdHorizontal`

Comment: i did it before its slice the background

Comment: Yes, because you're going to draw only one gradient (from start color to end color), not two of them, don't you ? I guess you're looking just for this line of code `GradientFillCanvas(Sender.Canvas, panelemo.Color, clWhite, ARect, gdHorizontal);`. But I'm giving up your questions. It seems that it's just me who cannot understand them (since people are voting them up).

Comment: i possibly can draw gdhorizontal and set rect to the same left and right ! , but my question how to exactly draw smoothly gradient like in image  i able to draw gdHorizontal but it looks sliced from center not smooth like in image

Comment: as example   `SetRect(R, ARect.Left, ARect.Top, ARect.Right - ((ARect.Right-ARect.Left) div 2), ARect.Bottom );
  GradientFillCanvas(Sender.Canvas, panelemo.Color, clWhite, R, gdHorizontal); // GraphUtil
  SetRect(R, ARect.left - ((ARect.Right-ARect.Left) div 2), ARect.Top, ARect.left, ARect.Bottom );
  GradientFillCanvas(Sender.Canvas, panelemo.Color, clWhite, R, gdHorizontal);` result looks very sliced

Comment: So, what does the "sliced" gradient look like when you use `gdHorizontal`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear what you actually want to have because what you say is different from what you show.

Anyhow, `gdHorizontal` means that the color is changing from `StartColor` to `EndColor` horizontally from left to right. In your image as if you would have specified white as start color and turqoise as end color. If you want to change the horizontal direction (to from right to left), you need to swap the colors.

Example of horizontal using code:

```
GradientFillCanvas(ListView1.Canvas, AColor, clWhite, R, gdHorizontal);
```

[image]

`gdVertical` means that the color is changing vertically, from top to bottom. If you want to change the vertical direction (to from bottom to top), you need to swap the colors.

Example of vertical using code:

```
GradientFillCanvas(ListView1.Canvas, AColor, clWhite, R, gdVertical);
```

[image]

The sliced result I think you refer to, is caused by the fact that you draw the gradient with two calls to `GradientFillCanvas()` once for each half of the `TRect`.

Comment: my original code shows from top to bottom  if you test this code after change in listview on draw `SetRect(R, ARect.Left, ARect.Top, ARect.Right - ((ARect.Right-ARect.Left) div 2), ARect.Bottom ); GradientFillCanvas(Sender.Canvas, panelemo.Color, clWhite, R, gdHorizontal); // GraphUtil SetRect(R, ARect.left - ((ARect.Right-ARect.Left) div 2), ARect.Top, ARect.left, ARect.Bottom ); GradientFillCanvas(Sender.Canvas, panelemo.Color, clWhite, R, gdHorizontal);` see how the result show up

Comment: and +1 for your example showing but thats not how its looks like in my code you can see after test

Comment: @DelphiStudent Read again my last paragraph. I know without testing that your listview is divided in two and each has its own gradient, IOW is "sliced" as you say. But why are you focusing on something you don't want? Do not divide the rect in two! Use only one call to GradientFillCanvas!